# How do I show that if $f(a)=0$, then $(x-a)$ is a factor of $f(x)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

a)If $p$ is prime, $f(x)\in \mathbb{Z}_{p}[x]$ is a polynomial, and $f(a)=0$, then $(x-a)$ is a factor of $f(x)$. Does it remains true if $p$ is not prime?

b) If $R$ is a commutative ring with identity. Let $p(x) \in R[x]$, show that $a \in R$ is a root of $p(x)$ if and only if $p(x)$ can be written as $p(x)=(x-a)g(x)$.

My idea:a), The first part is very easy by using Euclidean division algorithm.

If $p$ is not prime: Let $p=4$, $f(x)=x^{3}+x^2+x+1$, clearly, $f(1)=0$, and $f(x)=(x^2+1)(x+1)$, $f(x)$ does not have any factor of $(x-1)$. How do I make sure that this is the only factorization of $f(x)$?

In part b), $R$ is not a field, then can I apply Euclidean algorithm over a ring $R$.

I know that every finite integral domain is field; and  Is $R$ is a finite commutative ring with identity implies field?

Anyone suggest me some hint for both parts?

Comment: $(x-1)(x^2+2x+3)$ is a factorization in $Z_4$.

Comment: For the part b) you can prove that the remainder of the division of $p(x)$ by $(x-a)$ is $p(a)$.

Comment: @LorenzoRiva but in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ for $f=2x^2$ and $g=3x$ there is no exist $q$ and $r$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ for that equality.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the "if $p$ is not prime" question in part (a), you might want to look at part (b) and see if it applies.

For a direct proof of part (b), instead of trying to factor $p(x)$ directly, you could consider factoring $p(x)-p(a)$, which is equal to $p(x)$ since $a$ is a root. Or to put it differently, if you can prove the statement for polynomials of the form $p(x) = x^n - a^n$, then you are all set.